# Spring.net - PropertyRetrievingFactoryObject - property is null

Tags: inversion-of-control, spring.net

In an attempt to resolve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739102/different-behavior-in-get-vs-post-ajax-request) question, I'm taking a look at how our spring.net configuration works.

The root problem comes from this snippet:

```xml
<object name="someObject" singleton="false" type="SomeType.someObject, SomeAssembly">
  <constructor-arg name="authSession">
    <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyRetrievingFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
      <property name="TargetObject" ref="AuthSessionManager" />
      <property name="TargetProperty" value="CurrentAuthSession" />
    </object>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

In a case where a user is not logged in, `AuthSessionManager.CurrentAuthSession` will be null. When that is the case, Spring.NET throws an exception: "Factory object returned null object".

How can I tell Spring that the null object is acceptable in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [expression to retrieve an object from the spring context](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-object-references) in your constructor argument, something like:

```xml
<object name="someObject" singleton="false" 
        type="SomeType.someObject, SomeAssembly">
  <constructor-arg name="authSession" 
                   expression="@(AuthSessionManager).CurrentAuthSession" />
</object>
```

Expressions are allowed to evaluate to null, so you don't have to tell Spring anything.
This worked for me in a simple case (no nested contexts).

Comment: I ended up solving it a different way, but went back and tested with this and it worked also. Thanks! :D